Mapping a FTDI RS485 to USB converter mapped to serial inside a docker container
I have a FTDI serial to USB adapter that is connected to a server running Oracle Linux 9.2 and another piece of hardware.
I want to map it from ttyUSB0 in the operating system to ttyS0 in the docker container.
It has been set up using ansible as:
devices:
        - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyS0:rwm"

However, it is showing in the docker container as:
usb and serial
It seems to be connected as both serial and USB.
I have successfully done this on an ubuntu server with similar setup.  the baud rate and latency timer are both the same.
I have tried changing the ansible to
device_requests:
          - capabilities: 
              - rwm
            device: /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyS0
        tty: yes
        interactive: yes

However, I was unable and got an error from the docker:
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (community.docker.

I have also tried sending test messages through the terminal to light up the Tx LED,  This will only work through USB not through serial
echo -e "\x7E\x03\xD0\xAF und normaler Text" > /dev/ttyUSB0

and
echo -e "\x7E\x03\xD0\xAF und normaler Text" > /dev/ttyS0

